# Next.js Cannot destructure property 'publicRuntimeConfig' of '(0 , config_1.default)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';
  
const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();
```

getConfig always returns undefined after updating from Next 10.0.7 to 10.0.8 or any other version above. But everything works with any other version below 10.0.8

Comment: Are you using `getInitialProps` or `getServerSideProps` for that page where you are trying to access it? And in which part of the you are using it, server or client?

Comment: We have this function below which is stored in common folder to be used for both client and server, and it fails when it’s called on the server. And also we have getInitialProps in our _app.tsx file to opt-out of Automatic Static Optimization

export const getShopConfig = () => {
    const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

    return publicRuntimeConfig.shopConfig;
};

Comment: I'm afraid without a reproduction it will impossible to help, sounds like you do everything correctly. Try to make some minimal example which reproduces the issue. Like start a new empty Next.js app, see if it reproducible there? If not, then add some parts of your code and track when it starts to happen

Comment: This happens for me on running jest tests

Comment: Found any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/runtime-configuration) the feature is deprecated.

> This feature is deprecated. We recommend using [environment variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables) instead, which also can support reading runtime values.

You can use an [environment variable](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables) with the prefix `NEXT_PUBLIC_` and simply use `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_VARIABLE` wherever you need it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

In Jest, you can simply mock this using this code.

```
jest.mock("next/config", () => () => ({
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    contextPath: "",
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same issue because the getConfig() is depreciated

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35527191)